# How to make container 100% of parent if it have ul inside

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I have markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZVXFD/85/

i need to make `.step` of 100% of parent container, how to accomplish that.
html:

```
 <div class="steps-container">
        <div class="group">
            <div class="step">
                <ul class="sortable">
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
                <ul class="sortable">
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
                <ul class="sortable">
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                    <li class="item">Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

css:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sortable li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}


.group {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.step {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.item {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: you can specify the width=100% and height=100% of the .step

Comment: i have tried but it not work

Comment: You can't style a parent based on its children with CSS (yet). You'd need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: width:100% on .step expands it to be the size of group as you expect.  Are you wanting the li elements to fill into the extra space? http://jsfiddle.net/ZVXFD/88/

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B but i need make `.step` in line.

Comment: So you want step to be the same size as it's children, 100px? I guess I'm not following. If you want step to be 100% of it's container, there is no 'inline' representation of that. 100% is a full line..no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZVXFD/94/

If you want .group to be 100% wide, you'll need these styles:

```
.group {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:table; /* make the element 100% fill the entire available width */
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want .step to be equal height, you'll need these styles:

```
.step {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display:table-cell; /* make the element 100% of its parent's height/equal height columns */
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set `position: relative;` to `.group`

and

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

to `.step`

I'm assuming you are showing only one `.step` element at the time, am I wrong?